# Remove a value from a comma separated string in sql stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a field that store the comma separated id's of publications.  Such as 123456,2345678,123567,2345890 etc.  When I pull the data from the database I put it into a json object and the web page loops the values and displays the data.  Works great.

What I would like to do is to send the stored proc one of the numbers and the stored proc will remove it from the string and save it back to the table.  Such as the end user worked on publication 123567 and now wants to make it completed, so I want to remove it from the string so they don't see it in the future.  I have a split function in the database but I don't know how to wire it up to delete or rebuild the string without the publication ID.

I don't have any code to show because I am at a loss to start.  I figure I need to pass the entire string and the ID.  Split the string and loop each value to rebuild a new string but check if the ID is there and skip it.

Is this the best way to do this?

Thanks for your help

what I've ended up with as the base to work from is:

```
ALTER FUNCTION dbo.RemovePMID (
    @S VARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@PMID VARCHAR(15)
    )
RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @T VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @W VARCHAR(50)

    SET @T = ''

    WHILE len(@S) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @W = left(@S, charindex(',', @S + ',') - 1)

        IF charindex(@W, + @PMID) = 0
            SET @T = @T + ',' + @W
        SET @S = stuff(@S, 1, charindex(',', @S + ','), '')
    END

    RETURN substring(@T, 2, len(@T) - 2)
END
GO
```

Comment: Asking how to split a string, specifically a delimited string, in SQL is probably one of the most asked questions on SO; there are literally 100's of them, and probably 10's a week. You'll have very likely have had many of them proposed to you when you wrote this question. Didbyoh have a look at any of them? Ideally, however, you should be fixing your design, and single row and column should represent a single item, not many. Are you able/open to correct your table design?

Comment: Splitting the string is not the problem. Sorry I should have said that I have generic splitting functions  Removing the ID value seems to be the problem.  I'm working right now to create a tmp sting when I loop each value and if it is there then skip it.  The real question is- Is this the best way to do it or a simple replace if found with a charindex

Comment: There are far better ways to split a string than using a `CURSOR`. I'd suggest looking up `STRING_SPLIT` or `DelimitedSplit8K`. You'll be able to treat your data as a dataset then, and easily exclude the values you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for loops (please take a peek at Larnu's suggestion for your parse/split function)

That said, consider the following

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '123456,2345678,123567,2345890'

Declare @Zap varchar(50)='123456'

Select reverse(stuff(reverse(stuff(replace(','+@S+',',','+@Zap+',',','),1,1,'')),1,1,''))
```

**Returns**

```
2345678,123567,2345890
```

Comment: @user1314159 Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

It will remove a value from string

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '22,22,16,12'

Declare @Zap varchar(50)='22'

Select  STUFF((
                                SELECT ',' + s.value
                                FROM STRING_SPLIT(@S, ',') s
                                WHERE s.value NOT IN (SELECT @Zap)
                                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '');
```

which returns

```
16,12
```